# Notepad++ Folder as Workspace: what does the right button do?

Tags: notepad++

I'm starting to use Folder as Workspace. I have version 7.8.6.

I've tried all the buttons shown below and looked in the manual.

The leftmost button seems to open all the folder and sub-folders.

The middle button folds all folders and eventually lists all my work spaces. (My usual work spaces have >20000 nodes.)

What does the rightmost button do? (Circled.)

[image: circled button in question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows where the file in the currently active tab is placed in the list.